# Merge ComboBoxes functions

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, visual-studio-2015

I was trying to make `ComboBoxes` with `year`, `month`, `day` items. I did it. However, I need to DRY my code. Could you help me with that? I don't know, maybe I can't DRY this code because I'm overthinking.

```
/// <summary>
/// Function that fills comboboxes with items (values)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="date"></param>
public void cbItems(int year)
{
    ComboBoxItem cbItem = new ComboBoxItem();
    cbItem.Content = year;
    comboBox.Items.Add(cbItem);
}
public void cbItems1(int month)
{
    ComboBoxItem cbItem = new ComboBoxItem();
    cbItem.Content = month;
    comboBox1.Items.Add(cbItem);
}
public void cbItems2(int day)
{
    ComboBoxItem cbItem = new ComboBoxItem();
    cbItem.Content = day;
    comboBox2.Items.Add(cbItem);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with just one method but if you send the `ComboBox` as a parameter too like this:

```
public void cbItems(ComboBox cmb, int parameter)
{
     ComboBoxItem cbItem = new ComboBoxItem();
     cbItem.Content = parameter;
     cmb.Items.Add(cbItem);
}
```

Then for call it:

```
cbItems(combobox , 5);
cbItems(comboBox1 , 5);
cbItems(comboBox2, 5);
```